# uib-datepicker-popup: Only enabling certain dates for selection

Tags: datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

The docs/examples don't seem to cover this use case, nor have I found an example for this.

If I've got a list of dates, and want all other dates in this Datepicker disabled, what's the hook that would allow this?

I started by trying to use customClass just to mark the selectable dates from my list,  but there appears to be a bug such that customClass doesn't get called for uib-datepicker-popup.

Now I'm trying to use disable to mark all dates except those in my "available" list as disabled,  but there doesn't seem to be a way to iterate over dates in a range to apply the disable callback.